# Call to undefined method App\Mail\OrderPlaced::views()

Tags: php, laravel

i want to personalize message send to stripe, i did a test, i execute the command following `php artisan make: mail OrderPlaced`,
I have configured `app \ Mail \ OrderPlaced.php`

**OrderPlaced.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Order;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class OrderPlaced extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('admin@admin.com','Admin')
                    ->to('email@email.com','Name Person')
                    ->bcc('another@another.com')
                    ->subject('sublect line for the email')
                    ->views('emails.orders.placed');
    }
}
```

I add in the following line store

```
Mail :: send (new OrderPlaced);
```

I have created a blade `placed.blade.php` in root `views \ emails \ orders \ placed.blade.php`

**placed.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Email</title>
</head>
<body>
    this is the email that is being sent out.
</body>
</html>
```

but it gives me error `Class 'App \ Http \ Controllers \ OrderPlaced' not found`

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's an namespace issue.
The code is looking for `OrderPlaced` in the "Controllers" folder but you say that it's created under the "Mail" folder.

Try this:

```
Mail :: send (new \App\Mail\OrderPlaced);
```